# How to release connection with Apache http client property?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use Apache http client 4.1 and always close the response `InputStream` (e.g. by calling `EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity)`) after the `HttpGet` execution.

Now I wonder whether the connection is properly released if the `HttpGet` execution throws an exception. Should I release the connection explicitly in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Always close I/O objects in the `finally` clause if you acquired them.

```
InputStrem input = acquireStream( );

try
{
  useStream( input );
}
finally
{
  input.close( );
}
```